# How to check a constant variable using #if directives compile time in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, if-statement

The following code does not work as I expect using Visual Studio 2015, so it do not give a compile time error "ALIGN_SIZE must be divisible by 32". Is it possible to do something like this in compile time?

```
const static size_t ALIGN_SIZE = 65;
#if ALIGN_SIZE % 32 > 0
   #error ALIGN_SIZE must be divisible by 32
#endif
```

Comment: I suggest using [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) for this, not macros.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the [MSDN page on static_assert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293588.aspx). It has an example that covers this exact use case.
For example:

static_assert(sizeof(void *) == 4, "64-bit code generation is not supported.");

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the answer itself as the linked page might change and become useless.

Comment: Thank both of you for your help. That's exactly what I was looking for.